# visual studio 2015 professional after community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I had Visual Studio 2015 community version installed for a while and everything worked great.
I decided to upgrade to Professional so first I uninstalled the community version then installed the professional version and I keep getting errors I can get fixed no matter what. Most of the time its packages that are failing to load (its differet ones everythign i re-install) but also the Team Explorer isn't working at all and the solution explorer is blank..

Couldn't find any fix for it. I tried uninstalling with /uninstall /force - didn't help.
I tried deleting all sorts of registry keys and folders people suggested online - didn't work.

Im getting pretty desperate and beginning to think formatting the computer might be the only solution.

If anyone has a few good ideas I could try before that I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Ok
So the solution was to reinstall the community version then uninstall it using /uninstall /force

Then I installed the professional version again and now everything works.

Hope this helps someone someday!